# Insert into table from select across servers/engines using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach this.

Fundamentally, goal is to copy a table from one server/database to another. Therefore, I have two engines, one for the source and one for the target.

```
# create source connection
source_engine: Engine = create_engine(
    f"mssql+pyodbc://{source_server}/{source_database}?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
    fast_executemany=True,
    echo=True,
    logging_name="source_engine",
)

# instantiate MetaData object to hold source schema/table/view info
source_metadata: MetaData = MetaData()

destination_engine: Engine = create_engine(
    f"mssql+pyodbc://{destination_server}/{destination_database}?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
    fast_executemany=True,
    echo=True,
    logging_name="destination_engine",
)

destination_metadata: MetaData = MetaData(schema=destination_schema)
```

I'm trying the following:

1. Reflect the source table into a table object using the `autoload_with` option

```
source_object: Table = Table(
    source_object_name,
    source_metadata,
    autoload_with=source_engine,
    schema=source_schema,
)
```

2. Copy the source table into a new table object, changing schemas etc., using the `to_metadata` method

`destination_object: Table = source_object.to_metadata(destination_metadata, schema=None)`

3. Create the target table in the target server

`destination_object.create(destination_engine)`

So far so good. We now have a matching table setup in the destination target.

Now the stumbling block -- moving the data.

Ideally what I'd like to do is use something like the following in somewhat pseudo code:
`insert(destination_object).from_select(list_of_columns, select(source_object))`

But I don't know how to run the select in the source engine and the insert in destination engine.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

For the time being I've punted and resorted to first pulling the data into a dataframe and then using that to put into destination table.

```
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_sql(
    f"SELECT * FROM {source_schema}.{source_object_name}", source_engine
)

# convert the df to a list of dicts like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]
list_of_dicts: list[dict] = df.to_dict("records")

# create the insert construct against the destination table
ins = destination_object.insert()

# create context manager and insert records into the destination table
with destination_engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(ins, list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: "resorted to first pulling the data into a dataframe and then using that to put into destination table" - With two separate engines (and therefore two separate connections) you'll need to do something like that. Otherwise you'd need to set up a linked server or fiddle around with [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), but "ad hoc distributed queries" are disabled by default so you might need to have an admin enable them.